# Clone ONLY Windows 10 OS to another disk

Tags: windows, clone

In my HDD `C:` drive I have Windows 10.
Also I have this directory:
`C:\MyUltraHugeDirectory`

Now, I want to clone Windows 10 to a tiny SSD disk and keep MyUltraHugeDirectory in source disk.

Is this possible WITHOUT steps 1,2 & 4?

1. Backup & Delete MyUltraHugeDirectory directory from source partition.
2. Shrink source partition to fit to SSD disk.
3. Copy source partition to SSD disk.
4. Copy MyUltraHugeDirectory directory from my backup to source partition.

Comment: No, it's not possible without those steps. And you need also the ESP (EFI System Partition).

Comment: What you can do is save a disk image, most disk imaging software has the ability to exclude folders from the image, then restore that image to the SSD.

Comment: @Moab Can you tell me one? I prefer open source. E.g. CloneZilla does not know about files.

Comment: clonezilla is not the only choice

Comment: @Moab I don't know the rules of superuser. If it is not allowed to say commercial software, it is ok. Else, please tell me such a software. Thanks (BTW I reinstalled the Windows 10 to SSD, so the problem is not exist anymore, but your info is very useful).